# Connecting Cloud Composer in one region to Cloud SQL in another region (private ip) attached to same VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

Any help really appreciated from tech gigs in the field. I am relatively new to GCP and Google Cloud Composer. I am currently migrating from using a VM to a containerized solution using Cloud Composer using KubernetesPodOperator.

I have transitioned in a phase wise manner where Cloud SQL remains constant however my compute changes from Cloud Compute to Cloud Run (with an image) to Cloud Composer (multiple images to run) The question is in regards to connectivity from my Cloud Composer to Cloud SQL.

Set Up I have :

1. Spawned a Cloud Composer with GKE attached to my default VPC. (different region : Region B coz its not available in Region A)
2. My Cloud SQL has both private and public IPs enabled. (Region B)
3. My older Cloud Compute Instance. (Region B)

Things working well :

- Cloud Compute to Cloud SQL Connectivity:  Successfully able to connect to private IP of cloud SQL

**psql "sslmode=disable dbname=<MY_DB> user=postgres hostaddr="**

- Cloud Run with image of my code to Cloud SQL Connectivity : Successfully able to run the image when i set host as

**host = /cloudsql/PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID**

Things not working from Cloud Composer Instances :

- Cloud SQL private IP
- Cloud SQL public IP

** log of what gets printed as i launch my task via cloud composer**

```
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,300] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,488] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,489] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'    conn = connection.create_connection(\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,491] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,493] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'    raise err\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,494] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,496] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'    sock.connect(sa)\n'
[2021-05-26 07:16:40,498] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out\n*
```

- /cloudsql/PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID

** log when i use the above parameter as host **

```
*could not connect to server: No such file or directory\n'
[2021-05-26 08:54:03,899] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'\tIs the server running locally and accepting\n'
[2021-05-26 08:54:03,899] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'\tconnections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID/.s.PGSQL.5432"?\n'*
```

Kindly suggest

- Is there a fundamental flaw in how i have set up things ? Whats the difference between a Cloud Run setup and Cloud Composer. I have kept all things same but unable to run via Composer
- The only difference is that Composer is in a separate region than cloud sql. Can someone help me point out what should change because of this